# APT cannot install libc6:i386, unmet dependency

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies, steam

Obligatory searched the internet etc.

My Debian 11 system cannot install `steam` via `APT`. Many of it's dependencies rely on `libc6:i386` but `APT` complains that it is not installable. When I attempt to install it directly via `APT`, it complains that `hunspell-fr` (a dependency package) is uninstallable. However the default version of `hunspell-fr`, `hunspell-fr-classical`, which the dependency package depends on, is already installed on my system.

I've enabled the i386 architecture via dpkg, updated APT's index files and upgraded.I've also tried explicitly enabling `i386` packages by passing the `[ arch=amd64,i386 ]` option in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I've cleaned the index file cache and auto-removed orphaned dependencies. All sections are enabled including, `contrib` and `non-free`, for the `bullseye`, `bullseye-security` and `bullseye-updates` distributions.

```
nohatsatthetable@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

All help is appreciated!

### Terminal output when attempting to install `steam`:

```
nohatsatthetable@debian:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install steam
[sudo] password for nohatsatthetable: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not installable
 libbsd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libdrm2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
 libedit2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libelf1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libexpat1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 libffi7:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libgcc-s1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not installable
 libgl1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installable
               Depends: libglx0:i386 (= 1.3.2-1) but it is not installable
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libglvnd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libgpg-error0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libllvm11:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libmd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libpciaccess0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libsensors5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.23) but it is not installable
 libtinfo6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not installable
 libudev1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.30) but it is not installable
 libvulkan1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not installable or
                               vulkan-icd:i386
 libx11-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libxau6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libxdmcp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxext6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxinerama1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libz3-4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.30) but it is not installable
 libzstd1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 steam:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installable
              Recommends: libxss1:i386 but it is not installable
              Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
              Recommends: xdg-desktop-portal:i386
              Recommends: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk:i386 or
                          xdg-desktop-portal-backend:i386
              Recommends: xterm:i386 or
                          x-terminal-emulator:i386
              Recommends: zenity:i386
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Terminal output when attempting to install `libc6:i386`

```
nohatsatthetable@debian:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install libc6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hunspell-fr : Depends: hunspell-fr-classical but it is not going to be installed or
                        hunspell-fr-revised but it is not going to be installed or
                        hunspell-fr-comprehensive but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

### Output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

```
nohatsatthetable@debian:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

Comment: `steam` and `libc6:i386` don’t depend on `hunspell-fr` so that error is rather surprising. Could you [edit] your question to show the full output of `apt install steam` and `apt install libc6:i386`?

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks, I've added the output of `apt-get` to my post. Considering the purpose of `huspell-fr*`, I thought it unusual that `libc6:i386` should depend upon it, and as you say - it doesn't. What's even stranger is that `hunspell-fr-classical` is actually installed on my system.

Comment: Kind of a silly question, and you seem to know what you're doing, but after looking into the Debian package list hunspell-fr is a French dictionary. Are you French? As @Stephen-Kitt says, it isn't required by steam and libc6:i386 doesn't exist. Have you tried apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist upgrade?

Comment: The question says “I've enabled the i386 architecture via dpkg, updated APT's index files and upgraded.”

Comment: You're right, I didn't read that part correctly. 

I still cannot find a single package that is called that exactly on the Debian list, but my advice above is taken from [this askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023962/how-to-install-libc6i386-on-16-04-4-64bit). I am unsure on how to change mirrors from the cli, but that is the top answer. Other answers indicate doing what you've already tried. Perhaps try this suggestion: "I solved the problem by downloading libc6:i386.deb from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libc6 and executing 'sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i xxx1.deb'"

Comment: @ShutUpCaboose I'm not French, but looking at the reverse dependencies of `hunspell-fr` and checking them against `dpkg -l`, I see that there are three packages installed on my system that depend on it: `firefox-esr-l10n-fr`, `hunspell-fr-classical` and `task-french-desktop`. This is a very recent Debian install so I suspect `hunspell-fr` is included in the installation image by default as a dependency of something else. However as @Stephen-Kitt says, it is not included in the dependency tree of libc6:i386, so why `APT` still complains about it (esp when it is installed anyway) is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `hunspell-fr` solves one problem; however, there's a deeper problem: steam wants to install `libc6:amd64` and `libc6:i386`. As far as I can tell, something is broken is debian.

```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.36-7) but 2.31-13+deb11u5 is to be  installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.31-13+deb11u5) but 2.36-7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You are trying to install a version of `steam` that's intended for some distribution that uses libc6 version 2.36, and Debian 11 uses version 2.31. This is just the sort of dependency conflict that happens when you add repositories intended for other distributions than the one you're actually using. My Debian 11 with Steam installed gets it from repository `deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam` and the package to install is `steam-launcher`, not `steam` which is "a transitional package that can be safely removed once steam-launcher is installed".